# Jquery Scrolling background animation like scooby doo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm looking for some help with pointers on how to achieve a moving background similar to scooby doo or other another cartoons - eg on the press of a button the background slides right to left, the character animates (starts a GIF animation).

Im creating an animating character who will sit on a left hand side div. On clicking the character the div behind the character (the whole background, and other divs within in it) will slide from right to the left and a new div container will slide in to fill the gap. So essentially will appear like the character is walking but in fact the background behind him is moving from right to left.

I'm sure this must have been achieved before, but looking for some pointers on how best to achieve it. Any help will be appreciated.

My thinking is that on trigger there will be a few actions:

- GIF animation starts
- Whole div slides from right to left
- New div (which was hidden) is now shown
- New div slides from right to left, behind the old div
- Old div is hidden

The issue I am finding is creating a responsive site, therefore the size of the divs moving will not have a px value but a percentage value.

If anyone has tackled something similar before or has some pointers would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Negative margins or background-size: cover and you can change background position, so it looks like slide. Background repeat may be required to make infinite loop. And starting GIF animation is actualy not directly possible - there is workaround - you replace first frame static image with an actual GIF.

Comment: "The issue" I don't understand what you can't do using percentage? And still with JS you can calculate `$(window).width()` or `.height()`

Answer (score 0):

Getting myself a little confused here. I've worked this out by using a full sized owl carousel and sitting an absolute image over the top. Get my mind in gear!!